# whats wrong with this while loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Ok so I have spent hours trying to resolve this and I feel its some simple error but I cannot find a way to resolve this.
the section I am having issues with is the second half of the code. There seems to be an infinite loop somewhere among the 2 nested while loops. If anyone is able to help, this would be great, thanks in advance.

```
import sympy as sym
import random

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J = sym.symbols('A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J')
picks_a_person = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J] #List of people picking a name from a hat
person_gets_picked = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J] # List of names drawn from a hat
def re_draws(p):
    n = 0
    count = 0
    while n < 1000: #Repeats the test 1000 times for an accurate percentage
        n += 1
        random.shuffle(person_gets_picked) #Chooses a random order of the list of names drawn
        for i in range(p):
            if person_gets_picked[i] == picks_a_person[i]: #Checks for all 'p' elements of the lists are different
                count = count + 1
    print("count = " + str(count)) #Returns the number of times a re-draw was not required

import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

total = []
while len(total) < 1000:
    order = []
    picks_a_person = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
    person_gets_picked = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
    while len(order) < 10:
        a = person_gets_picked[random.randint(0, (len(person_gets_picked)-1))]
        if a != picks_a_person[0]:
            order.append(a)
            person_gets_picked.remove(a)
            del picks_a_person[0]
    total.append(order)
Counter(np.array(total)[:,1])
```

Comment: put `print(...)` to whatever you are trying to decrease for debugging. for example `len(order)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are a lot of odd things about your code, this is where it gets into an infinite loop:

```
picks_a_person = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
person_gets_picked = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
while len(order) < 10:
    a = person_gets_picked[random.randint(0, (len(person_gets_picked)-1))]
    if a != picks_a_person[0]:
        order.append(a)
        person_gets_picked.remove(a)
        del picks_a_person[0]
total.append(order)
```

Let's do some rubber duck debugging - what happens when your `random.randint(0, (len(person_gets_picked)-1))` returns a number larger than `0` nine times in a row (worst case scenario)? All `person_gets_picked` elements except `A` get removed and added to the `order` list (which is still under `10` elements to break away from the `while` loop).

At that point we have a state as `picks_a_person = [A]` and `person_gets_picked = [A]`. `random.randint(0, (len(person_gets_picked)-1))` will, thus, always return `0`, `a` will always be set to `A` and since `picks_a_person[0] == A` the condition `if a != picks_a_person[0]` will never be evaluated as `True`, hence the `order` will never get its 10th element and therefore you got yourself an infinite loop.

It doesn't even have to be *nine positive numbers in a row* for this to occur - all it needs to happen is for `A` to remain as one of the last two picks and for random to land on the other option.

So why don't you write your whole loop as:

```
persons = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
persons_num = len(persons)
total = [random.sample(persons, persons_num) for _ in range(1000)]
```

And you're done.